# How can I use JointJS with an application built with Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, jointjs

I have installed jointjs via npm and also installed typings
and code compiles/builds fine.

Code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import  * as joint from '../../node_modules/jointjs/dist/joint.min';


export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  constructor(
  ) {
    // console.log(joint)// private jint: joint,
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
  }
}
```

Error shows up on the browser:

```
Failed to compile.

/home/vinay/angularapps/jjs/src/app/app.component.ts (17,31): Property 'Graph' does not exist on type '{}'.)
```

my cli.json file.. added the scripts and styles for jointjs

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.32.3",
    "name": "jjs"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/jointjs/css/layout.css"
      ],
      "scripts": ["../node_modules/jointjs/dist/joint.js"],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "files": "src/**/*.ts",
      "project": "src/tsconfig.json"
    },
    {
      "files": "e2e/**/*.ts",
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

my tsconfig.json file where i added allowJs to true

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am not able to figure out how to create a simple hello world application   provided on this link 
http://resources.jointjs.com/tutorial/hello-world

Comment: format your post and ad the list of errors you get.

Comment: Can you share your full angular-cli.json?

Comment: shared the full angular cli

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ok i finally got to get jointjs working with @angular cli and below are the steps

**in the command prompt** within the angular project directory

1. ng new your-app
2. cd into your-app
3. npm install jquery --save npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
4. npm install backbone --save npm install @types/backbone --save-dev
5. npm install jointjs --save npm install @types/jointjs --save-dev
6. npm install lodash@3.10.1 --save npm install @types/lodash@3.10.1
   --save-dev

Make sure **in package.json** the entries show up under dependencies and devDepencies for
backbone, jquery, jointjs, lodash and make sure they are of the versions

jointjs 1.0.3, backbome = 1.3.3, jquery = 3.1.1, lodash = 3.10.1

in **angular-cli.json** file

in the styles property and scripts;[ ] property add the joint js details like below

```json
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/jointjs/css/layout.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/jointjs/dist/joint.js"
  ],
```

in **your component.html**

```html
 <div id="paper"></div>
```

in **your component.ts**

```js
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import * as $ from 'backbone';
const joint = require('../../../../node_modules/jointjs/dist/joint.js');

ngOnInit() {
    let graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

    let paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
      el: jQuery("#paper"),
      width: 600,
      height: 200,
      model: graph,
      gridSize: 1
    });

    let rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
      position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
      size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
      attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } }
    });

    let rect2 = rect.clone() as joint.shapes.basic.Rect;
    rect2.translate(300);

    var link = new joint.dia.Link({
      source: { id: rect.id },
      target: { id: rect2.id }
    });

    graph.addCells([rect, rect2, link]);
}
```

Comment: please note if lodash is not the version that jointjs recommends it will throw errors so i had to install lodash with the version number. the others like backbone, jquery etc installed with the right version without having to mention them

Comment: In the official documentation the rect.translate is there, but when i try to ng serve it says, property translate doesnt exist on type 'Cell'. How do I fix this error?

Comment: See [JointJS Official docs](https://www.jointjs.com/opensource#Download-JointJS) for the latest recommended versions of dependencies for the current jointjs.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using @angular/cli : 1.0.4 version and im going to sum everything you need to run JointJS without a problem.

Use these commands to install npm packages correctly and make sure the right versions are present. Types on devdependencies and the libraries on normal dependencies  thats important.

```
npm install --save lodash@3.10.1 jquery@3.1.1 backbone jointjs
npm install --save-dev @types/lodash@3.10.1 @types/jquery @types/backbone @types/jointjs
```

This is my scripts in the angular-cli.json file:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/lodash/index.js",
    "../node_modules/backbone/backbone.js",
    "../node_modules/jointjs/dist/joint.js"
  ]
```

This is my styles in the angular-cli.json file to work properly:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.scss",
    "../node_modules/jointjs/css/layout.css",
    "../node_modules/jointjs/css/themes/material.css",
    "../node_modules/jointjs/css/themes/default.css"
  ],
```

And the examples are same as above.
Hope i could help. Happy Coding!

Comment: "scripts" part here is the correct one! Guys, don't forget about backbone/lodash inclusion as it leads to 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$' of undefined' issue.

Answer (score 4):

Just to mention there are a few things wrong or missing in the accepted answer:

1. includes in component.ts should be:

   ```
   declare var $:JQueryStatic;
   import * as _ from 'lodash';
   import * as backbone from 'backbone';
   import * as joint from 'jointjs';
   ```
2. you should add the version on the npm install commands for jquery and backbone to ensure to use the suggestioned version as mentioned.
3. you also (additionaly) must add following 2 css files into angular-cli.json:

   ```
   "../node_modules/jointjs/css/themes/material.css",
   "../node_modules/jointjs/css/themes/default.css"
   ```
4. use $ in the code rather than jQuery:

   ```
   let paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
      el: $('#paper'),
      ...
    });
   ```

hth some one,

PS: i tested it with angular 4.1 and angular-cli 1.0.3

Comment: It works. The only issue is that application throwing exception for Backbone:

`scripts.bundle.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$' of undefined`

Related piece of code:
`var Backbone = root.Backbone;`
`var _ = root._;`
`var $ = Backbone.$ = root.jQuery || root.$; // <-- this is reported as an issue`

Answer (score 1):

1. `npm install jointjs --save`
2. at angular.cli.json insert at scripts : `./node_modules/jointjs/dist/jointjs.js`
3. at angular.cli.json insert at styles : `./node_modules/jointjs/css/layout.css`